# C# Lambda Return Statement Question

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, anonymous-function

Hey all, quick question on how to call this lambda or what it actually does..

```
public Composite CreateBuffCheckAndCast(string name, UnitSelectDelegate onUnit, CanRunDecoratorDelegate extra)
{
    return new Decorator(
        ret => Spells.CanBuff(name, onUnit(ret)) && extra(ret),
        new Action(ret => Spells.Buff(name, onUnit(ret))));
}
```

Unfortunately don't have the rest of this class and haven't used Lambdas in a while.. Where does that "ret" variable come from?  The calling function?  Is it used to grab an IEnumerable  I could see the compiler assigning it whatever type onUnit would accept..?

Solution:

ret => is used to transform Spells.CanBuff into a delegate type to be accepted by Decorator.  The onUnit would also accept a delegate function parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "Does this apply to the above function or is Lambda used another way"?

Comment: Can you show me the correct way to call CreateBuffCheckAndCast, then populate the ret lambda variable?

Comment: You don't populate the ret /parameter/.  No lambda expressions are being returned from CreateBuffCheckAndCast, just a Composite (which happens to be a Decorator).  So you can only do things to it that a Composite can do, whatever that is for the library you are using.

Comment: The second code sample has a totally different return type ... it's returning an Action<ISyncClient>, meaning an Action that takes an ISyncClient as a parameter and returns void.  Since it's returning an action, you can pass the parameter for sc, in the returned lambda expression.  You can't do that for the first code snippet ... like I said, it returns a Composite, not a Func or Action.

Comment: Understood, wanted the explanation.  I'm trying to learn the code not just use a library. So thank you!  I don't like magic code. =)
Didn't quite get where the lambda fit in there, but I'm getting it now.

Comment: Note that when you have a Func or Action, you can do something like var f = new Func<string>(() => "Foo"); string foo = f(); // invokes f, which returns "Foo" and assigns "Foo" to foo.  What f() is /really/ doing is f.Invoke().  Same with your earlier example action(sc) ... it's really action.Invoke(sc).  This only works for delegates (i.e. Func, Action, or an anonymous delegate, (or other Delegates)) which a lambda expression is.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to explain, that's my favorite part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ret` variable is the parameter to the delegate (or expression tree) that the lambda expression is building. Note that the `ret` for the first lambda expression is a different `ret` to the one in the second lambda expression.

So, two delegates are created, and they are passed to the `Decorator` constructor, which presumably stores them to execute them later on. When each delegate is called, the caller will have to pass a value in which will be available as the `ret` parameter during the lambda expression's execution.

Without seeing what the signature of the `Decorator` constructor is, it's hard to say any more than that.

I'm not quite sure what the relevance of your second snippet of code is, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks.. very fast!  The 2nd snippet doesn't have anything to deal with the first so don't be afraid haha.  I was trying to show my understanding of using lambda's (expression modifier at least).

http://code.google.com/p/treesharp/source/browse/trunk/TreeSharp/Decorator.cs

I guess my question is on how to exactly call that.  Do I call the function like normal, capturing the return "Component" then use that with a parameter that will take the place of "ret".  Sorry if I'm way off!

Comment: @BruceBannor: Do you call what function? You've got umpteen things you *might* be wanting to call, but you haven't really explained what you're trying to do...

Comment: I'm only interested in this function.. CreateBuffCheckAndCast.  Please ignore the 2nd snippet.  How would you call that function then, call the delegate from that?  (I know you don't have any delegate functions made, etc, etc)

Comment: @BruceBannor: Well to *call* `CreateBuffCheckAndCast` you just need argument values for all of the relevant parameters. We don't really know what those delegate types mean... but you could create delegates from lambda expressions, or from existing methods. The fact that the implementation uses a lambda expression should be irrelevant to you. We also don't know what the `Composite` type exposes. Basically you're the only one with the information about the types involved. My advice is to ignore the lambda expression and concentrate on what `Composite` exposes.

Comment: ok that's the answer I was looking for.. sorry I'm getting up to speed.  Thank for the patience!

Answer (score 2):

A lambda is an anonymous function. So in your case, `ret` is the parameter to the function.

When you do say

```
Func<int, int> myFunc = (f) => f + 1;
```

You are defining an anonymous function that takes an int and returns it + 1. You are storing a reference to the anonymous function in the `myFunc` reference. This function has not executed, it's just been defined. You can later call the function whenever you like:

```
int a = myFunc(4);   // a becomes 5
```

An `Action<T>` is a delegate that returns void and usually points to a lambda such as yours. a `Func<T1, T2>` is a delegate that takes a `T1` and returns a `T2`, and also usually points to a lambda. There are other delegates defined for other methods that take more parameters such as `Func<T1, T2, T3>` and `Action<T1, T2>`

In your case you are handing the Decorator two anonymous functions. When it deems necessary, it will call them to do some work for it, and use the return value to further its own work.

Comment: Thanks, I got that down pat.  I wasn't quite sure how to use the first snippet though.

    Composite myComposite = CreateBuffCheckAndCast("blah", "blah");
    myComposite(retValue);

Anywhere close?  Can't get code to format in comments.